# formatting phone numbers ms access

Tags: ms-access, phone-number

Sorry, another question about MsAccess.

I have data set:

```
Phone Number
444-514-9864
555-722-2273
333-553- 4535
000-000- 0000
550-322-6888
444-896-5371
322-533-1448
222.449.2931
222.314.5208
222.745.6001
```

I need it to look like (222) 896-5371.
How do I do it in Ms Access or MsExcel?

Comment: Are you willing to use VBA for this? there is an easy way to do this in vba

Comment: if it's possible doing it in vba ..and easier than using Replace function....  please explain how do I do it..    Thank you!

Comment: Well, i did use the replace function (see my answer) but you could also filter out the first 3 numbers and the last 7 in 2 different string variables  (Prefix and Suffix) and then in the end you do something like: ` Newphonenumber = "(" & prefix & ")" & suffix

Comment: Care to accept an answer or improving your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Instr, mid, Left and Right functions to make this work. I have made 1 example, with msdn you should be able to figure out the rest

```
Dim OldPhoneNumber As String
Dim NewPhoneNumber As String
Dim PreFix As String
Dim PreFix2 As String

' You can replace this line in Access, just make sure the full phone number is stored in "OldPhoneNumber"
OldPhoneNumber = Worksheets(<worksheet name>).Range(<cell name>).Value 


PreFix = Left(OldPhoneNumber, InStr(1, OldPhoneNumber, "-", 1))
PreFix2 = Left(OldPhoneNumber, InStr(1, OldPhoneNumber, "-", 1) - 1)

NewPhoneNumber = Replace(OldPhoneNumber, PreFix, "(" & PreFix2 & ") ")

Debug.Print (NewPhoneNumber)
```

Seeing as not all your phone numbers are formatted the same way, you would have to make a different rule for every different formatted phone number (you need 1 that checks for **"-"** and one that checks for **"."** You also might want to filter out the **spaces**

Answer (score 0):

In Access you set the "Input mask" to : **"("000") "000"-"0000;1;_**

All the references http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/input-mask-syntax-and-examples-HP005187550.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work.  Even after I applied mask,  +1.444.854.5100  has not been changed to (444) 854-5100  My fields already have phone numbers. Mask works only for the new inputs

Comment: Maybe create a [macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-macro-HA010030811.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Input mask will only work for new data.  You will need to create a macro or function to update your existing data to be consistent with your desired format